# 2/0 AWG or 3/0 AWG

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

What size wire should I use for a 200 AMP service disconnect per NEC?  Seeing conflicting information.  Also should it be Al or Cu clad and THHN or THWN or dual rated? It is outside directly under the meter in a box that goes directly through the wall to an inside breaker box.

Comment: Looks to me like you get an 83% derate because it is service entrance and then go to the standard table which gets you 2/0 Cu or 4/0 Al. But I am far from certain. THWN because W = Wet for outdoors. But also need to consider conduit type - what type/size do you have or are you going to get? May even make sense to use actual cable for such a short run, which is quite common.

Comment: If you're downstream of a main disconnect, you do not get the same derate that the utility gets, meaning 3/0 copper or 250 kcmil aluminum. You'll need to check what wire sizes the disconnects and panels that you can actually acquire accept and that may influence which wire you go with. Aluminum is perfectly safe and far less expensive than copper, but if the run is very short and you need to fit on lugs that don't accept 250kcmil, the copper may win.

Comment: @nobody You keep that same derate until the first split (i.e., up to the first "real panel", even if it is a subpanel if the disconnect has the ground). Actually, I think you get to always keep that (e.g., if you feed a 200A subpanel off of a 200A main panel) and never have to go larger. But if you have 400A service feeding 2 x 200A panels, those (and any subsequent feeds) don't get the 83%.

Answer (score 3):

For all intents and purposes Copper Clad Aluminum isn't available, and THHN is only available as dual rated as THWN. For size choose 2/0 copper, for price choose 4/0 aluminum.

For single family dwellings a special 83% rule applies to  the normal 310.16 ampacities. The NEC keeps making wording and locations changes that have essentially no effect except to cause confusion. The current applicable 2020/2023 NEC Code reference and applicable table is quoted word for word as Texas Electrical Code at [Upcodes](https://up.codes/s/single-phase-dwelling-services-and-feeders).

Comment: If the above link grows stale the same info can be seen at https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=878.0 or more complicated route at https://link.nfpa.org/free-access/publications/70/2023

Comment: +1 for proper spelling of "intents and purposes"! The other info is good too... ;)

Comment: So I shouldn't send a barge-load of *Intensive Porpoises* your way, @FreeMan ? They were so looking forward to the trip...

Comment: It's been raining here, @Ecnerwal, but not enough for that...

Answer (score 2):

A "Service" is what the utility sells you, and it begins at their provided electric meter.  It comes in various sizes from 30A to 600A.

For a 200A service to a dwelling, you need 4/0 aluminum.  This is also usable for any feeder off that 200A service, even if it would normally require 250 kcmil.

For all other cases of 200A, (non-resi service; feeder off a 225A+ service; etc.) you need 250 kcmil aluminum.

If you are constrained by conduit diameter, you can use 2/0 *copper* under the dwelling rules, or 3/0 *copper* for all other uses. **However, you'll go broke if you do**, and it won't buy you a thing - all the lugs that the wires will land on are made of aluminum.

Comment: Back on this project after a bit of a hiatus.  Will this be acceptable for both the meter to service disconnect and service disconnect to main breaker panel?  Both are short runs (under 6 feet).
https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-4-0-4-0-4-0-2-0-Aluminum-Ser-Service-Entrance-Cable-By-the-Foot/3127469

Comment: @Fleet yeah that should be fine provided it does not need physical protection.  If it does, run RMC/IMC conduit and then 4/0 XHHW individual wires.

Comment: Thanks.  Plan was Sch. 40 conduit for 6” run from meter to service disconnect, then straight into the exterior wall stud bay from the back of the disconnect to the main panel inside.  We assumed no conduit/protection needed inside the stud bay for a short run less than 1 foot.  Is that correct if we use the SER cable?

Comment: I would use RMC/IMC for the 6" run from meter to disconnect, because it's metal and it neatly solves the dilemma of how to ground the meter pan.  Assuming the disconnect is a breaker, the ongoing run should then be circuit breaker protected.  You still need to protect it from nails etc.

Comment: Thanks @harper.  You’ve been very helpful.

Comment: Project is drawn out due to remote location, but utility company finally upgraded the line from the transformer to the weatherhead to 200 Amps.  We ordered SER 4/0 4/0 4/0 2/0 for cabling from new service disconnect to sub panel inside house, and SEU 4/0 4/0 2/0 from his link https://www.platt.com/p/0069560/seu-service-entrance-cable-2-4-0-awg-stranded-aluminum-500/662927129051/4a22a1seuax500

Comment: Will the SEU cable be acceptable?  I intended to purchase SEU 4/0 4/0 4/0, but saw my error when cable arrived.

Comment: @Fleet As long as the SEU is for going up from main disconnect to service point, should be fine.  You have a population of 240V loads in the house, right?

Comment: Yes.  Nothing over 240V load.  It will need inspection prior to turning power back on, so I wanted to be sure.  Thanks so much for your help!